# глубокое копирование объекта

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как реализовать глубокое копирование объектов в java. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28195274 - `My_Object object2= org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone(object1);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596565 - используя сериализацию (не проверял, теоретически, должно работать):

Если класс `final` или не может быть изменен, нужно `implement` интерфейс `serializable`. Преобразовываем класс в поток байтов:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(object);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
bos.close();
byte[] byteData = bos.toByteArray();
```

Далее, возобновляем объект класса с потока байтов:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData);
(Object) object = (Object) new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java - больше ответов, указаны разные библиотеки для данной цели.

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы не просто накидаете ссылок на SO, а переведете подходящий ответ, сохранив ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека для клонирования доступна здесь: https://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Глубокое клонирование с этой библиотекой сводится с двум строкам кода:

```java
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
DeepCloneable clone = cloner.deepClone(this);
```